# Cloned node isn't equal to original node (with isEqualNode)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm managing a list of names in Javascript. When you check a box, your name appears in the list. When you uncheck it, it gets crossed out. And when you set the box to the indeterminate state, your name's removed.

I've got the name of the currently logged in user in a hidden div. The name is a span with style attributes.

I check if the name is already in the list with isEqualNode. When it's in the list when the page loads, it works fine: the name is found and so is updated when the box checked state change.

```
for(var i=0 ; i < bullet.childNodes.length ; i++) {
    var node = bullet.childNodes[i];
    if(node.className == 'crossed')
        node = node.firstChild;
    if(node.isEqualNode(document.getElementById('curUser').firstChild))
        break;
}
// if i < bullet.childNodes.length, then we found the user's name in the list
```

When the name is not in the list, I clone the span.

```
var newName = document.getElementById('curUser').firstChild.cloneNode(true);
bullet.appendChild(newName);
```

This works, visually.

But I stumbled on something tricky: `newName.isEqualNode(document.getElementById('curUser').firstChild)` is false! So if the box state change again, the newly added name won't be found and a new one will be created, again.

Here is what the span looks like:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold ; color: #003380 ;">Pikrass</span>
```

For the moment I'll just make the check less strict (I can just check the text data inside the span instead of relying on isEqualNode), but I'm interested in why a cloned node can be different than the original one, according to isEqualNode.

Relevant specs : [cloneNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4), [isEqualNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-isEqualNode)

---

**EDIT:** I tested with Firefox and Chromium. With Firefox isEqualNode returns false, but with Chromium it returns true. Thanks Felix for pointing this out.

Comment: Which browser? It seems to work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/WhxQP/.

Comment: Interesting question. Here's a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/QtJJb/

Comment: This fiddle is not working in Firefox 17.x.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: It does not work in Chrome either, and it's because `.clone` does not seem to copy the ID attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/WhxQP/1. If you remove the ID, it works fine.

Comment: So, it seems that `.clone` does not copy the ID attribute, which would explain the differences. In your example though, the `span` element does not have an ID attribute. Does it in your actual code?

Comment: Sounds logic. :) Here's a updated fiddle where ID will be removed before cloning: http://jsfiddle.net/QtJJb/2/

Comment: @Felix Kling: I recommend you to publish that as an answer.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Since no ID is used in the example, I don't know if this is the actual problem. Will wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Felix: I'm using Firefox, and your fiddle alerts false. So this could be a bug in Gecko.

Comment: The second fiddle returns 3 times true as expected. My first fiddle was wrong as Felix sayd, `clone()` removed the ID, that's why the nodes do not equal. Both in Firefox 17.x and Chrome 22.x (Linux).

Comment: Have you tried normalizing the nodes before your equality-check as recommended by the specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never. :)

I can't reproduce the issue anymore with Firefox 17, so as discussed in comments this was probably a bug in Gecko, which has then been fixed.

I couldn't find any bug report however. I flag this answer as accepted for now, but if someone can find the bug report or an explanation of what was going on under the hoods I'll accept that instead.

Bergi's comments are right for the two other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Just figured this out. According to [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/DOM3-Core.html#core-Node3-isEqualNode), isEqualNode returns true only if both elements have equal amount of attributes. But if the source element has an ID, it is not copied since IDs shoud be unique, so it has less attributes. With class instead of ID it works fine.

Markup:

```
<div id="withId">withId content</div>
<div class="withoutId">withoutId content</div>
```

JS:

```
function test(node) {
    var copy = node.clone(true);
    document.body.appendChild(copy);
    console.log('are equal: ' + copy.isEqualNode(node)
        + ', attributes lengths: ' + node.attributes.length + ' ' + copy.attributes.length
        + ', ids: ' + node.getAttribute('id') + ' ' + copy.getAttribute('id'));
}

test(document.getElementById('withId'));
// are equal: false, attributes lengths: 1 0, ids: withId null

test(document.getElementsByClassName('withoutId')[0]);
// are equal: true, attributes lengths: 1 1, ids: null null
```

http://jsfiddle.net/igorz/fxtDw/

Comment: Why should ids not be copied? The W3 spec does not say so, and even [Mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode) explicitly states "*`cloneNode()` may lead to duplicate element IDs in a document*".

Answer (score 2):

It is written here [Mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode%20Mozilla) (thanks @Bergi)

> The duplicate node returned by cloneNode() receives a new uniqueID when it is added to another node

As you are doing an append, the id is probably changed at this moment.

Comment: I think that only refers to the internal `uniqueID` (as in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIAccessNode#Attributes)), which should not be considered by `isEqualNode`